# Vertically resizing only 1 of 3 divs to fit window?

Tags: html, css, resize, responsive

I'm trying to make a what should be a simple responsive page that consists of several divs as depicted below:

```
<div id="container"> maximum 1200 width and 1000 height
    <div id="vertically-static-top">20 pixes high</div>
    <div id="vertically-resizeable-middle">adjustable height</div>
    <div id="vertically-static-bottom">50 pixels high</div>
</div>
```

the overall max-width and max-height are 1200 and 1000 respectively

vertically-static divs must only resize horizontally if the browser window is resized, but vertically they need to always be fixed in height

vertically-resizeable div needs to adjust both its width and height based on the window dimensions.

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to get that middle div to resize vertically and keep everything inside the browser window!

Thank you so much!

Comment: `max-height: 100%` should be enough to keep that element vertically flexible to the viewport height. Do you have any other styles, maybe inherited ones, that could be preventing that element from growing or shrinking below a particular height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with flexbox. Here is the sample code:

```css
#container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
  -ms-flex-direction: column!important;
  flex-direction: column!important;
  height: 240px;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 1000px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

#vertically-static-top,
#vertically-static-bottom {
  background-color: #80bdff;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#vertically-resizeable-middle {
  background-color: #957bbe;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  color: #fff;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"> maximum 1200 width and 1000 height
    <div id="vertically-static-top">20 pixes high</div>
    <div id="vertically-resizeable-middle">adjustable height</div>
    <div id="vertically-static-bottom">50 pixels high</div>
</div>
```

adjust the height of #container (`height: 240px;`) or put 100% instead to fit parent element's height

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use position **`absolute`**. Check below snippet.

```css
html,
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  max-height: 1000px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#vertically-static-top,
#vertically-static-bottom,
#vertically-resizeable-middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#vertically-static-top {
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
}

#vertically-static-bottom {
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
}

#vertically-resizeable-middle {
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="vertically-static-top">20 pixes high</div>
  <div id="vertically-resizeable-middle">adjustable height</div>
  <div id="vertically-static-bottom">50 pixels high</div>
</div>
```

I hope this will work.